# Send array of Infrared codes

Tags: serial, bluetooth, arduino-nano, softwareserial

I'm having a bit of a problem when sending IR Codes stored in variables. I swear I had this convered up already. I don't actually know the reason why I can't use variables in the first place. I receive data over Bluetooth Serial Com and I'm using an Arduino ProMicro as ISP for the Arduino Nano.

I want to send data over Serial comm and then send an IR code to the end receiver.

Here is some of the code():

```
#include <IRremote.h> // IR Library - Encode/Decode

void irSerial( char SerChar[] ) // Receive array of characters

char IDChar[]={'s', 'i', 'u'}; // List of Serial Char to identify position
String HRD[]={"Power", "Input", "ChaUp"}; // Action referece 
byte CodesIR[]={0x61A0F00F, 0x61A048B7, 0x61A050AF}; // IR Codes
int IRArray = 2; // Size Of The array

if ( SerChar[0] == 's' ) { // Compare Array
  for (int CountIR = 0; CountIR <= IRArray; CountIR++){ // Loop through array
    if ( SerChar[0] == IDChar[CountIR]) {
       bluetooth.println(HRD[CountIR]); // Send String in array - Works
       SendIR.sendNEC(CodesIR[CountIR],32); // Send IR in array position
    }
  }
}
}
```

There's not a problem with the current expression as it compiles normally and I can send serial data normally finishing the function. If I replace the array **CodesIR[CountIR]** for example with **0x61A0F00F** then it works perfectly.

How can I use a variable instead? Can anyone help? It is the **byte CodesIR[]** ??

I used a **Switch/Case** and it works but I prefer a variable/array and less useless coding. Thanks for understanding!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? I don't know what library you're using, but it seems to me that you try to compare if SerChar[0..2] is equal to IDChar[0..2], and send the corresponding code for those that are equal. Maybe you could include a bit more code or an explanation

Comment: Well yes I'm comparing those values based on what I receive over serial. Everything works fine. The thing is that it seems I'm not using the correct data type for the IR codes. I'll rephrase my question! Thanks for your concern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well as usual it was something stupid (-__-) I changed the **byte** array for **long** and it worked perfectly.

Here is the complete code working():

```
#include <IRremote.h> // IR Library - Encode/Decode

void irSerial( char SerChar[] ) { // Receive array of characters

    char IDChar[]={'s', 'i', 'u'}; // List of Serial Char to identify position
    String HRD[]={"Power", "Input", "ChaUp"}; // Action reference 
    long CodesIR[]={0x61A0F00F, 0x61A048B7, 0x61A050AF}; // IR Codes
    int IRArray = 3; // Size Of The array # Edit

    if ( SerChar[0] == 's' ) { // Compare Array
      for (int CountIR = 0; CountIR < IRArray; CountIR++){ // Loop through array # Edit
        if ( SerChar[0] == IDChar[CountIR]) {
           Serial.println(HRD[CountIR]); // Send String in array - Works
           SendIR.sendNEC(CodesIR[CountIR],32); // Send IR in array position
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great job. P.S. To make your code a bit more intuitive, you could change `IRArray = 2` to `IRArray = 3`, and then use `CountIR < IRArray` for the loop.

Comment: Thanks! I'll hope this could be of some help. I'll edit my response following your advice. Many thanks for pointing that out.